# how to create ini file as HDFS on linux

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, apache-sentry

I am new to linux. Cloudera [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-0-x/CDH5-Security-Guide/cdh5sg_sentry.html#concept_xxk_x1p_wk_unique_2) has mentioned creating sentry-provider.ini file on cloudera CHD 5.4 as HDFS file.  I am not finding good article on how to create ini file on linux.

I am trying to configure Apache Sentry on cloudera setup to have role based security on hive metadata

how to create ini file as HDFS on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is: You can create this "sentry-provider.ini" file on your local (on linux terminal)

```
vi sentry-provider.ini
```

Then put the content specified at this [link](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-0-x/CDH5-Security-Guide/cdh5sg_sentry.html#concept_xxk_x1p_wk_unique_2) in the file by pressing `i` and then pasting the content.
After this put the file on HDFS file system using command :

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal sentry-provider.ini etc/sentry/
```

Remember that the path `etc/sentry/` is the path on HDFS from your user's home directory which is typically `/user/username/`

Comment: how to identify on which host Hiveserver2 is running on ?

Comment: As far as creating the file in HDFS is concerned, you don't have to worry about on which host Hiveserver is located. Because when you put file in HDFS, its available for all hosts in the filesystem.

Comment: If you have Cloudera Manager configured, from UI, you can find out which service is running on which host.